# Semamtic UI: Disable dimmer associated with a modal

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I have a modal that accepts some user input. If the user gets the right answer, he/she should be able to see the animation behind the dimmer. I have tried

```
$('.basic.modal')
.modal('setting',{
    closable  : true,
    onDeny    : function(){},
    onApprove : function(){}
})
.modal('hide others')
.modal('show')
.modal('hide dimmer');
```

and

```
$('.basic.modal')
.modal('setting',{
    closable  : true,
    onDeny    : function(){},
    onApprove : function(){}
})
.modal('hide others')
.modal('hide dimmer')
.modal('show');
```

Neither worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

You can hide the dimmer by passing the opacity to the dimmerSettings like this:

```js
$('#your-modal').modal({
  dimmerSettings: { opacity: 0 }
}).modal('show');
```

Answer found [here](http://www.projecttalk.io/boards/Semantic-Org%2FSemantic-UI/topics/111)

Comment: The problem with this is that if the page is longer than the window, the dimmer will still remove the scrollbar when the modal appears, causing a small horizontal shift in the window content.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set 'hide dimmer' after the modal has shown.

```
$('.basic.modal')
.modal('setting',{
    closable  : true,
    onDeny    : function(){},
    onApprove : function(){}
})
.modal('hide others')
.modal('show')
.modal('hide dimmer');
```

Comment: Doesn't looks like a valid answer, when I use this solution my modal is being hidden, too. Have you tried it?

Comment: Perhaps you were using an old version of SUI, but `.modal('hide dimmer')` does work. It's not ideal though because the dimmer flashes on for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to go about it.

```
.ui.dimmer{
    background: transparent;
}
```

How did you end up solving it?

Comment: that seems like a hack. But, to add to the hack, you could also add `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove dimmer from onShow callback like that:

```
$('.modal').modal({
        duration: 10,
        onShow: function () {
            $('.modal').parent().removeClass('dimmer');
        }
    }).modal('show');
    ;
```